# Eclipse and test packages now in white and un-runnable

Tags: eclipse, testing, icons, package

I have an issue with Eclipse and my test packages. They show as white icons instead of the default brown color normally used in Eclipse for packages... See image below:[image: eclipse screen capture]

what is more I can't run my tests from Eclipse now. I must be missing a basic configuration somewhere.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think these packages have been 'excluded' from the build path. (That's how I can make packages/classes look that way)

Right click on the "given project" --> "Build Path" --> "Configure build path".

See the "Source" tab. For each source folder you have three subsections: Included, Excluded, Native Library location.

Check if there are files/packages excluded.

Comment: including **/ *.scala in 'Included' location(along with already present **/ *.java) solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

That is because the name of your class (DAOTest.scala) is in .scala format.
If you convert into .java i.e.(DAOTest.java) format you'll get the brown icons.